# Removing unnecessary modules from react-boilerplate

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-boilerplate

I installed react-boilerplate and noticed hundreds of node modules that I don't actively use. Is there any way to remove unused project? or are those dependencies of dependencies that get all installed at root level in node_modules and if so, is there any way to tidy up modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with my knowledge, I can claim that you can customize your boilerplate with anything that you want, but every module has their own dependencies which they are required. I suggest that before doing anything read  more about boilerplate  and about customization and its use